# Conditional formatting formula for each line in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have 2 pages - Sales and Warehouse in my sheet:

Sales:

- ID column (Column A),

Warehouse:

- ID (Column A),
- Stock Balance (Column H).

I would like to apply conditional formatting for those IDs on the Sales page whose Stock Balance is 0 on the Warehouse page.

The issue is that there are a lot of different IDs. Is it possible to do it with custom formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by going to the `Sales page` up where it says `Format => Conditional Formatting`

Then put the following parameters:

- Apply to range: `A2:A`
- Custom formula: `=vlookup(A2,indirect("Warehouse!A2:H"),8,false) = 0`

**Note:** The `8` before before the `false` in the formula is the difference between your column H and A, so if you want any other columns, please change it to other number, or look at the [official docs of vlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Your result should be something like the following:

Sales:
[image]

Warehouse:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, this only works if the order of the IDs on the 2 pages is the same. In other words, the formatting is applied to the same lines on the Sales page where the condition on the Warehouse page is met. I need the condition to be applied to all IDs, regardless of their order and number of repetitions. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I updated my answer to match your problem, let me know if it helped